# Correction in Published Paper

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, paper-submission

One of my papers were published in a good journal. But Recently I have identified a  major flaw in my methodology. I want to correct it. Is there a way to correct it within the same published paper? Or, do I need to publish the corrected one in another journal?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can't just change an already published version. However, this does not mean that you should just publish the correction in another journal. The best way to deal with it would be to contact the editor of the original journal and discuss things with him, as this error also concerns him, not only you. He will then be able to tell you how to publish the correction.
In case that you aren't the only author (e.g. you have an advisor, colleagues, etc.), they should also be informed before taking action.

Comment: That is, it is possible to correct it within the same publication. Is there a chance that editor cannot take steps to correct it?

Comment: And another question: will this affect my future publication in that journal?

Comment: @user149054 I's say that most scientists have at least one article with minor or major flaws.